# Mining 7 days worth of Tweets from Twitter API with a certain hashtag using Python Tweepy

Tags: python, django, orm, celery, tweepy

I am mining 7 days worth of Tweets from the Twitter API using Python, Tweepy, Django, Celery, Django REST framework.

I am sending a request every minute using a celery beat and storing the collected data to a Postgresql database using the Django ORM.

To ensure that the api doesn't keep sending the same 100 tweets with each call, I am checking the database for the `min(tweet.id)`, and setting that as `max_id` parameter before each new request.

I ran into a problem: once I get 7 days worth of tweets, how do I reset this `max_id`.

### models.py

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    tweet_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        unique=True,
        primary_key=True
    )
    tweet_date = models.DateTimeField()
    tweet_source = models.TextField()
    tweet_favorite_cnt = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tweet_retweet_cnt = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tweet_text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet_id + '  |  ' + str(self.tweet_date)
```

### tasks.py

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# Instantiate an instance of the API class from the tweepy library.
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)


@shared_task(name='cleanup')
def cleanup():
    """
    Check database for records older than 7 days.
    Delete them if they exist.
    """
    Tweet.objects.filter(tweet_date__lte=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)).delete()


@shared_task(name='get_tweets')
def get_tweets():
    """Get some tweets from the twitter api and store them to the db."""

    # Subtasks
    chain = cleanup.s()
    chain()

    # Check for the minimum tweet_id and set it as max_id.
    # This ensures the API call doesn't keep getting the same tweets.
    max_id = min([tweet.tweet_id for tweet in Tweet.objects.all()])

    # Make the call to the Twitter Search API.
    tweets = api.search(
        q='#python',
        max_id=max_id,
        count=100
    )

    # Store the collected data into lists.
    tweets_date = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_id = [tweet.id for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_source = [tweet.source for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_favorite_cnt = [tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_retweet_cnt = [tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_text = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]

    # Iterate over these lists and save the items as fields for new records in the database.
    for i, j, k, l, m, n in zip(
            tweets_id,
            tweets_date,
            tweets_source,
            tweets_favorite_cnt,
            tweets_retweet_cnt,
            tweets_text
    ):
        try:
            Tweet.objects.create(
                tweet_id=i,
                tweet_date=j,
                tweet_source=k,
                tweet_favorite_cnt=l,
                tweet_retweet_cnt=m,
                tweet_text=n,
            )
        except IntegrityError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Check for the minimum tweet_id and set it as max_id.
# This ensures the API call doesn't keep getting the same tweets.

date_partition = get_seven_day_partition
## Since you're cutting off every seven days, you should know how
## to separate your weeks into seven day sections

max_id = min([tweet.tweet_id for tweet in Tweet.objects.all()
              if tweet.tweet_date > date_partition])
```

You didn't specify enough info about how you're pulling these tweets and how you know to stop at a certain date (and the execution of this program) so it's hard to advise a proper way of keeping track of date.

What I can tell you is, set `date_partition` accordingly for your use case and this addition to the `max_id` assignment will properly grab the max day for the oldest 7 day period